# Cannot resolve findViewById - fetching data from multiple fields

Tags: java, android

I can't get my code to resolve findViewById - I've got a method that takes two pieces of data from a custom dialog box, but if I use findViewById to try and fetch the data, I just get that it can't resolve it.

See this excerpt:

```
public class ItemsActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ArrayList<Item> itemlistv = new ArrayList<Item>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);


    populateListView();

    final Button addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add_item);
    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ItemsActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = ItemsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

            alert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_additems, null))

            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    Editable itemname = (Editable)dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
                    Editable itemprice = (Editable)dialog.findViewById(R.id.itemprice);
                    //String itemnamestring = itemname.getText().toString();
                   // itemlistv.add(new Item(itemname, itemprice));
                    populateListView();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // End of dialog
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }

    });

// etc
```

I just cannot get findViewById to work here, but I've got it working in other classes absolutely fine within my program. Have I made a silly mistake?

Ignore the two commented lines, I know they're not right - I'm focusing on why I can't get findByViewId in this instance.

Many thanks

Alex

Comment: Think I've got it - should be
Editable itemname = (Editable)findViewById(R.id.itemname);
                    Editable itemprice = (Editable)findViewById(R.id.itemprice);

Answer (score 0):

Don't search for the View fields in Dialog. Do something like below instead -

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ItemsActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
final View modifyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_additems, null);
final Editable itemname = (Editable)modifyView.findViewById(R.id.itemname);
final Editable itemprice = (Editable)modifyView.findViewById(R.id.itemprice);
alert.setView(modifyView)
.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
         //String itemnamestring = itemname.getText().toString();
        // itemlistv.add(new Item(itemname, itemprice));
         populateListView();
     }
 })
 //your code
```